# error attempting to use convert-tslint-to-eslint

Tags: angular, migration, eslint, tslint, angular17

The first step

```
    ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

executes successfully but the second step

```
    ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint
```

produces this error:

```
    Error: The `convert-tslint-to-eslint` schematic is no longer supported.

    Please see https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/docs/MIGRATING_FROM_TSLINT.md
```

and the readme document referenced in the error message is the one I was following to attempt this migration.

I successfully used this schematic about about three weeks ago.

Has anyone else encountered this error message? Know of a workaround?

```
Angular CLI: 17.0.7
Node: 18.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 17.0.7
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.7
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.7
@schematics/angular             17.0.7
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2
zone.js                         0.14.2
```

Comment: Just curious is this a new Angular 17 project or have you upgraded from a previous version of Angular to v17?

Comment: @Phalgun this project was recently upgraded, step-by-step, from Angular 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using tslint with an earlier version of Angular, then this tslint to eslint conversion should have been done at a stage when Angular version less than 16.

From [MIGRATING_FROM_TSLINT.md](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/docs/MIGRATING_FROM_TSLINT.md),

> As a community project we need to focus on what adds the most value to
> the majority of our users, and so, in version 16, this conversion
> tooling was removed.
>
> If you want to leverage it, you can of course use it on a major
> version of Angular + angular-eslint prior to version 16, or you can
> feel free to take the implementation from our git history and leverage
> the schematics inline in your own projects.

Comment: Thanks, @Phalgun... this little tidbit is a good candidate for inclusion in the Angular Update Guide.

Comment: what are our options if we upgraded to 16 before running the schematic?

Comment: If you committed the changes after every version update, you could consider reverting back.